# Is wmode="transparent" attribute required in both the <object tag as well as the <embed tag?

Tags: html, flash

To get flash to sit behind html elements on a page I read that I have to add this inside the object tag:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
```

And this to the embed tag:

```
wmode="transparent"
```

Is it necessary to add both? Because in FF I got it to work with just the second, just wondering if that may cause issues in other browsers and devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers use the `<object>` some use the `<embed>`, you need to add wmode to both to support all browsers